# Javacv - IplImage.createFrom() - rpoblem with allocation

Tags: javacv

When i execute my code some times it work fine, but once for aprox. 7 execution apperars error. Error message :

javacv Bad argument (unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvReleaseData

My code:

```
File imageFile = new File("/home/user/java.jpg");  
BufferedImage bufferedImage= ImageIO.read(imageFile);  
IplImage poColorPhoto = IplImage.createFrom(bufferedImage); // here sometimes appear error  
IplImage poGrayPhoto = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(poColorPhoto), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
cvCvtColor(poColorPhoto, poGrayPhoto, CV_BGR2GRAY); 
poColorPhoto.release();
```

Comment: Do you still get that error with the latest version of JavaCV? If so, can you open an issue on the Web site? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the 3 first lines for something like this:
IplImage poColorPhoto = opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage("yourImage.png");

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating an IplImage of same width and height as of your BufferedImage like this:

```
IplImage ipl_image = IplImage.create(your_buffered_image.getWidth(), your_buffered_image.getHeight(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

and then assign BufferedImage to your IplImage like this:

```
ipl_image = IplImage.createFrom(your_buffered_image);
```

Hope this helps.